# How to pass Current user to Django_filters ModelChoiceFilter queryset

Tags: python, django, django-filter

How to pass Current user to [Django_filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) `ModelChoiceFilter` queryset.

I'm trying to filter the `ModelChoiceFilter` based on the current user , i've used the `init` method in the filter but it failed:

here is the code I've used :

**views.py**

```py
def requests_reports(request):
    f = RequestsFilter(request.GET, queryset=LeaveRequest.objects.filter(user=request.user), user=request.user)
    context = {
        'filter': f,
    }
    return render(request, 'requests_reports.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class RequestsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(RequestsFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(user=self.user)

    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='gt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='lt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ['employee', 'type']
```

It returns this error :

```
'RequestsFilter' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the normal `_init_` but instead of `self.fields['field_name]` use `self.filters[field_name]`

Try this code:

```py
class RequestsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(user=self.user)
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='gt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='lt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    employee = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=None, field_name='employee' )
    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ['employee', 'type', 'date_time']
```

Comment: Popping the user seems to be not possible with django 3.1 anymore. I had to pop the request: `request = kwargs.pop('request')
        user = request.user
`
But i dont know if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the following in the **init** of the filterset:

```
user = kwargs['request'].user
```

For example, this is from my project but I hope it helps someone:

```
class MenuItemListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs['request'].user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['section'].queryset = MenuSection.objects.filter(business=user.business)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experiance in Django, but what I see is you can not use meta attributes inside just like `self.fields`, you have to find another way to do it.

you can find more information on how to use filters [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can set a custom method. More info here: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method

```
class RequestsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    employee = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='employee',
        queryset=Employee.objects.all(),
        method="filter_employee",
    )
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='gt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name='date_time', lookup_expr='lt', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = LeaveRequest
        fields = ['employee', 'type']

    def filter_employee(self, queryset, name, value):
        qs = queryset.filter(user=self.user).filter(**{name: value})
        if len(qs) >= 1:
            return qs[0]
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: i did it and returned this error        

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: well then put .get() in the end of filter or [0]